# Software to backup directory to another HDD without file container

Tags: backup

I have directory with MP3 files about 500GB in folders and sub-folders with new MP3 constantly being added and/or existing folders being rearranged under new sub-folders.

Need to backup to external hard drive, however i don't want delete and copy over entire folder every time as it takes 10 hours.

Looking for backup software for Windows 7 (only software with GUI, not command line) that will mirror contents of source folder to another location i.e. **only copy new files and/or delete files that does not exist in source anymore.**

P.S. Don't want to use backup utility that creates a backup file container and then do incremental/differential backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restricting yourself to GUI only programs is a bad idea, command-line programs just need to be configured once and using a batch file they are as easy to use like any other GUI program.

I always use the command-line tool `robocopy` in mirror mode for keeping a copy of media files on a second HDD. It exactly works the way you have outlined: copy new files and delete files that do no longer exists in the source folder (recursively).

robocopy is included in Windows 7/10 and is very reliable, you just have to build a batch file with all the parameters you need. My favorite combination is

```
robocopy <src folder> <dest folder> /MIR /XJ /NDL /NP /TEE /LOG:Backup.log
```

parameters:

- `/MIR` mirror mode: mirror source folder to destination folder
- `/XJ` do not follow symbolic links
- `/NDL` do not log directory names (makes the log file easier to read)
- `/NP` no progress while copying the files
- `/TEE` Print to console and to log file
- `/LOG:...` Create a log file